# How to store result of cmd using Popen with option (input=password) in syntax as mandatory

Tags: python-3.x, popen, samba

Part of script  in the code, below, is work partial to me, in another words, executed samba-tool command and bring me result on the screen (python3 script.py). BUT,  the value of process (variable) is all none.

I tried/read documentations, but without success to store and fix it.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE, STDOUT

def run_command():
    process  = Popen(['samba-tool', 'dns','query','chaps.xpto.local','xpto.local','@','ALL','-U','auditor'], stdin=PIPE).communicate(input=b'@!3202@otpX')
    print(process)

run_command()
~
```

I tried:

```
outs, errs = Popen(['****')
print (outs)
```

or

```
print (process.stdout)
```

I tried to use StringIO to capturing, but  sysout of command Popen doesn't record tool

Comment: I don't notice anything glaringly wrong, after referencing the documentation for popen here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ryanwebjackson.

After days suffer with it, I notice that problem is only for syntax samba-tools to query dns information, because the  arguments need to inform login/pwd to query and if try capture
output doesn´t works, the utility not understands a valid credetials/bad password.
If i try the syntax  to use with other utility or shell commands work well. I decided change the approach and replace :

```
process  = Popen(['samba-tool', 'dns','query','chaps.xpto.local','xpto.local','@','ALL','-U','auditor'], stdin=PIPE).communicate(input=b'@!3202@otpX')
```

For :

```
process = subprocess.getoutput("(($(dig +noall +answer "+host+"."+domain+" |wc -c)>0)) && echo exist")
```

I had the list of host to test if there's records on DNS and zone and voila! fixed.